# Blender 2.8 Bone pose local and global axis mismatch

Tags: bones, pose-mode, axis, transform-orientation

I need my bone local axis to be exactly the same as global axis. It's not true at least with the Y axis. I already tried applying current pose as rest pose, but it's not helping. In armature edit object mode, the local and global axis are identical. Please could you help me make this true for the pose mode as well?

[image: Bone rotates around itself instead of global Y axis.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bones Y axis is always the longitudinal axis, and this cannot be changed, but you can extrude from its head another bone, orient it as you want (along with world coordinates I guess) and the set it to be the parent of the deforming bone.