# Bone Axes Mismatch

Tags: rigging, axis

I'm just learning the very basics of rigging. I found a tutorial that details how to align a bone's local axis to the global axis. The same issue is covered in this post :

[Blender 2.8 Bone pose local and global axis mismatch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174184/blender-2-8-bone-pose-local-and-global-axis-mismatch)

When I tried this, I found they were already aligned, so I'm guessing it was addressed in the later version of Blender that I'm using (3.1). I'm confused though because when I enable Axes under Object Data Properties > Viewport Display, it doesn't match the Local Axes. See attached.

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are in the *Object Mode*. It displays object orientation itself, not the bone's orientation. Change the mode to  *Pose Mode*. *Edit mode* also shows object orientation, instead of bones ones, I suppose, that it is so to match the behavior with mesh edit mode.

Comment: Thank you. I actually just this second managed to figure this out. Very confusing for a beginner !